# How to send an email trigger for a new form response entry in a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that creates new entries in a google sheet, I want to send an email to a specific person whenever a new entry is created, i.e. set up a trigger that actively tracks additions of entry in the sheet, how do I do this?

Comment: [Google it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+form+email+notification)

Answer (score 0):

You should [set up](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) the Form Submit trigger:

```
function onFormSubmit(eventObject) {
    /* 
     *  Code to extract & parse data from eventObject.response
     */
    MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body);
}
```

Additional References:
[Form Submit Trigger Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_3)
[Form Response Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)
[MailApp sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

Comment: Thanks, do I enter run this script on the form or on the sheet? While on sheet, it only sends an email when I run it manually and not on a form submission.

Comment: Open Google Form > Goto options (three dots) > Script Editor > Write your script and install on form submit  trigger